# rotating 3D object around the center

Tags: opengl, graphics, glut, transformation

I have object moving from A to B on x-axis and there is no translation of object apart from it. Now, while moving, i want to rotate it around y-axis and the motion should change accordingly, i mean if i rotate it right when moving from -x to +x axis, it should move towards near plane that is in z-direction. I am using perspective projection. I have variable in gltranslatef which is modified in the loop after that i have glscalef to scale whole object which is made of hierarchical structure. Now i tried following code to achieve the expected result but its not working properly.

```
 glTranslatef(move, 0, 0);

// If I comment these 3 lines, it does not affect the output
     glTranslatef(-move, 0, 0);
glRotatef(rotate,0,1,0);
glTranslatef(move, 0, 0);

glScalef(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use deprecated function, all those 4 functions are deprecated, try learning the new and better ways of doing these things.

Comment: I have to implement it using above calls only

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not accurate enough.
On one hand you mention to rotate it around the y-axis. On the other hand it should move towards the near plane.

The important question is: How have you setup your projection matrix?
In general, what you try to achieve in your code doesn't look too bad. However, you maybe have setup an orthogonal projection matrix.

Comment: So, what you try to achieve is:
You have a drawable that moves along the x-axis but also comes closer to the camera when moving from left to right?
If not, where is your camera pointed at?

Comment: my camera is along z. Assume you are going on a road and you want to take a turn to right and continue in that direction.